# How to shuffle within a specific dimension in a multidimensional array of complex numbers

Tags: arrays, matlab, random, complex-numbers

I want to shuffle a 3-dimensional array with complex values, in such a way that elements are randomly rearranged along the 3rd dimension only.

For example, the 3D array of *integers* A (I remind that I'm looking for the same solution but for *complex* numbers array):

```
A(:,:1)= 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9
A(:,:2)= 10 11 12; 13 14 15 ; 16 17 18
```

After shuffling the third dimension, a possible output could be:

```
A(:,:1)= 10 2 3 ; 4 14 6 ; 7 17 18
A(:,:2)= 1 11 12; 13 5 15 ; 16 8 9
```

How can I do this?

The [only solution](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27076-shuffle) I've found includes compiled c function which doesn't work with a complex-valued array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very simply iterate over the first two dimensions, and permute the elements along the third one:

```matlab
a = randn(3,5,2) + 1i*randn(3,5,2); % some complex data

for jj=1:size(a,2)
  for ii=1:size(a,1)
    a(ii,jj,:) = a(ii,jj,randperm(size(a,3)));
  end
end
```

Note that this solution is likely faster than the `cellfun` solution in the other answer for very large arrays, as that solution requires large intermediate data to be stored and used.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use the same permutation for each iteration instead of using randperm?

Comment: @SharonasYkm: What do you mean? Do you want to apply the same permutation to the whole array? If so, you don't need a loop at all, it's much simpler! `a(:,:,:) = a(:,:,randperm(size(a,3)));`

Comment: Yes, but only within the third dimension.

Comment: @SharonasYkm: That's what the one-liner in my comment above does, it applies the same permutation to each `a(ii,jj,:)` vector. Your example in the question applies a different permutation to each vector, as does the code in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized way:

```
A = cat(3, [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9], [10 11 12; 13 14 15; 16 17 18]); % define data
s = size(A); % get size of A
[~, ind] = sort(rand(s), 3); % indices of random permutations along 3rd dim
result = A(reshape(1:s(1)*s(2),s(1),s(2)) + (ind-1)*s(1)*s(2)); % linear index and result
```

Comment: Very clever. But does use more memory than the loop! :p

Answer (score 1):

the below script does a random shuffling in the 3rd dimension,

```
% creating a sample data, can be complex numbers
x=magic(10);
x=reshape(x,[4,5,5]);

% split 3D matrix into 2D cell arrays of vectors, permute those, and get back to 3D
y=num2cell(x,3);
newy=cellfun(@(x) x(randperm(length(x))), y,'uni',false);
newx=cell2mat(newy);
```

you can call `permute` followed by `num2cell` to partition your 3D array in different ways to shuffle it in a different dimension, for example,

```
x=permute(x,[2,3,1]);
y=num2cell(x,3);
```

the above code will create a 5x5 cell arrays of vectors of 4 elements (i.e. the 1st dimension), then you can use `cellfun/cell2mat` to do a random shuffling of the 1st dimension, then call `permute` again to change it back to the original dimension order.